# Networking in unityscript Unity3D

Tags: function, networking, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unityscript

what is the analog of `Networkview.ismine` method in unityscript?

The problem is when I create server and connect to it, two players are appeared. When I try to move one of them, both players move simultaneously at the same direction.

All the scripts are written in unityscript, so I need analog of Network.isMine method in unityscript, which returns boolean

Does someone know this?

Comment: Are you referring to UnityScript, Unity's javascript-like language?  If so, networkView.IsMine is implemented across all languages [in their engine](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/NetworkView-isMine.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your capitalization? It's `networkView.isMine` (not NetworkView.ismine). Like Jerdak commented, it should be present in UnityScript without modification.